# How to change pinned Taskbar Icon of Whatsapp?

Tags: windows, taskbar, icons, shortcuts, desktop-customization

On my Windows I have the Whatsapp App installed from Windows Store.

Now I would like to change its Icon, without luck so far.

I tried following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70507827/5437864) and it does create a taskbar Icon that opens Whatsapp having a different icon, but Whatsapp opens in a new Taskbar icon with its original and does not stack.

The aim is to have a secondary Whatsapp (beta) installed for another account using a different color.

Comment: What you want isn’t possible. What is possible with a traditional Windows desktop isn’t always possible with UWP applications like you find on the Microsoft Store.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can do this, is by editing the .exe file with a resource editor and change it there.

This is not really a good solution though because any update will undo the changes, and WhatsApp will update them frequently.

There is no other way however.

Comment: If it's a MS Store "app", then I believe one cannot edit the files successfully -- there are checksums for each component, including logos, according to tests reported done for a similar question.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I know this to be true for apps that live in the WindowsStoreApp folder, but WhatsApp for Desktop does not live there, so I'm not entirely sure if this is going to fail anyway.

Comment: @LPChip - Author indicates it’s whatsApp from the Windows Store

Comment: @Ramhound That would be unfortunate. Windows used to be customizable, I'm afraid they are changing